# sleep from main thread is throwing InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the main thread of execution which spawns new threads. In the main thread of execution in main() I am calling `Thread.sleep()`. When do I get an *Unhandled exception* type `InterruptedException`?.

I am unsure of why am  I getting this. I thought this was because I needed a reference to the main thread so I went ahead and made a reference to it via `Thread.currentThread()`.

Is this not the way to have the thread sleep? What I need to do is have the main thread wait/sleep/delay till it does it required work again.

Comment: Any code would be much appreciated :).

Comment: Well all I'm doing or have done has called Thread.sleep(some amount of milliseconds) or made a reference to my main thread (I think thats what it was doing) with Thread t = Thread.currentThread() and then calling t.sleep(some amount of milliseconds). Both cases have thrown the InterruptedException.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you see is a compilation error, due to the fact that you didn't handle the checked exception (`InterruptedException` in this case) properly. Handling means doing one of the following:

1) Declaring the method as `throws InterruptedException`, thus requiring the caller to handle the exception

2) Catching it with a `try{..}catch(..){..}` block. For example:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1500);
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("got interrupted!");
}
```

`InterruptedException` is used to indicate that the current thread has been interrupted by an external thread while it was performing some blocking operation (e.g. interruptible IO, wait, sleep)

Answer (score 0):

At the line where you're definition of **main** starts, just include **throws Exception**. I too was facing similar problem, and this helped. After this inclusion, you need not include the **Thread.sleep(xx);** inside a try-catch statement

Answer (score -4):

```
Thread.sleep(t);
```

This is how you can make your thread wait. where t is in milliseconds.
It is working fine in my main method, so to find out your problem it would be better if you can provide your code here.